# what happens if i rename namespace in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I need a Clarification, regarding Flex.
what happens if i rename namesapace in

```
 <mx:Module xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Replacing as

```
<mx:Module xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
   xmlns:dx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
   xmlns:ot="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Need to Know why and what happens if i Do like this...

Thankxx in Advance!!

Comment: if you redefine `mx` prefix, then you shall use your `ot` for `Module`: `<ot:Module ...`

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier to try this than to write up the question?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting by an example, this is how things will change:

**BEFORE**

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%">
   <mx:ViewStack id="mainStack"  top="0" bottom="0"
                 width="100%" height="100%"
                 >
                 <mx:VBox>
                    <s:CheckBox  selected="true"/>
                 </mx:VBox>
    </mx:ViewStack>
```

**AFTER**

```
<ddd:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:ddd="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:yyy="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

        <yyy:ViewStack id="mainStack"  top="0" bottom="0"
              width="100%" height="100%"
              >
    <yyy:VBox>
        <ddd:CheckBox  selected="true"/>
    </yyy:VBox>
</yyy:ViewStack>
```